# Using iterators to read binary integer list from file

Tags: c++, file, binary, iterator

I'm looking for a way to use iterators to fill a `std::vector` container when reading binary integers from a file using `std::ifstream`.

I tried the following method:

```
std::vector<int> indices;
indices.reserve(index_count);
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(ifstream), std::istream_iterator<int>(), std::back_inserter(indices));
```

But no entries are added.  I've read that this method might only works for strings?

Anyways, any advice would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "binary integers"? Are the raw integer bytes in the file?

Comment: @Cameron Yep, raw bytes.

Comment: Ah, in that case there's no need to use iterators. Simply copy in the bytes (and be careful with endianness -- the raw bytes of integers are not portable across all processors). Something like `indices.reserve(index_count); ifstream.read((char*)&indices[0], sizeof(int) * index_count);` should do the trick.

Comment: You would want to use `resize` not `reserve`

Comment: @Retired: Oops, good catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to write your own iterator to do this. It's not useful to do - it would be slow because every `++` of the iterator you would do another read (that's a lot of reads, or at least a lot more than have to be there).

If you have a file purely of ints...

```
std::ifstream is("filename.ints", std::ios::binary|std::ios::in);
is.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
auto length = is.tellg();
is.seekg(0)

std::vector<int> ints(length/sizeof(int), 0);
is.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(ints.data()), ints.size()*sizeof(int));
```